# PostgreSQLで、特定のDBのサイズ（不要領域を除く）を知りたい

Tags: postgresql, database

PostgreSQLで、特定のDBのサイズ（不要領域を除く）を知りたいのですが、

```
select pg_database_size('DBNAME');
```

として得られるサイズは、不要領域も含む実サイズのようで、ここから VACUUM 後に減るであろうサイズにできるだけ近い
不要領域を除いたサイズが知りたいのですが、何か良い方法はあるでしょうか？

できるだけ軽い方法だとありがたいのですが。